# Remove a commit based on its message content or filename with git filter-repo --commit-callback

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I am attempting to remove a commit from my repository history based on its message or filename by using `commit.skip()` . However, it seems that once the conditional statement evaluates to true, all subsequent commits in the history are skipped, irrespective of the condition.

The code I have been using to skip a commit based on its filename is the following:

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback 
 for change in commit.file_changes:
  if b"index" in change.filename:
   commit.skip()
```

whereas for skip a commit based on its message content is the following:

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback 
 if b"index" in commit.message:
  commit.skip()
```

The logic of the conditionals is correct, as when I use

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback 
 if b"index" in commit.message:
  commit.message = b"new commit message"
```

it works perfectly fine, affecting only the commits which respect the conditional statement.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Since this is almost identical to [an example in the documentation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#removing-commits-by-a-certain-author), I think it looks like a bug. Might be worth opening an issue on the git-filter-repo repository.

Comment: I thought the same too. This is why [I opened a discussion about it](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/discussions/533). I have also checked the git filter-repo documentation without finding any useful specification on how `commit.skip()` works. It seems that the `skip()` action [remove](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) all commits that satisfy the specified condition/s. However I will follow your advice and open an issue on the git filter-repo repository.